# How to remove one duplicated line by XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file:

```
<Picture id="001.png"/>

<Line/>

<Picture id="002.png"/>

<Line/>

<Picture id="003.png"/>
```

and want to change it to:

```
<Picture id="001.png"/>

<Line/>

<Picture id="002.png"/>
```

I can remove "003.png" by the following xsl, because I know its id, but don't know how to remove the "Line" above it.

```
 <xsl:template
     match="//Picture[@id='003.png']">
 </xsl:template>
```

can I do it by following-sibling? 
thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with following-sibling. Change the code from Eero Helenius as follow.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <!-- Identity transform -->
      <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <!--
      Drop unwanted elements: <Line> with fist following-sibling::Picture id = '003.png
      <Picture id="003.png"/>
      -->
      <xsl:template match="Picture[@id = '003.png']"/>

      <xsl:template match="Line">
          <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Picture[1][@id = '003.png'])">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this code: <xsl:template match="Line">
          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::Picture[1][@id = '003.png']">
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>

Comment: @iclinux: If you really use the code above (without any xsl:copy or other output statement in the match="Line" template it would not be surprising that there is no "Line" tag anymore in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Your input isn't well-formed XML because it doesn't have a root element, but here's one option:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
  Drop unwanted elements: <Picture id="003.png"/> and the <Line/> element
  preceding it
  -->
  <xsl:template
    match="Line[following-sibling::*[1][self::Picture[@id = '003.png']]]
         | Picture[@id = '003.png']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<Elements>
  <Picture id="001.png"/>
  <Line/>
  <Picture id="002.png"/>
  <Line/>
  <Picture id="003.png"/>
</Elements>
```

#### Output

```
<Elements>
  <Picture id="001.png"/>
  <Line/>
  <Picture id="002.png"/>
</Elements>
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't know the index of that "Line", what I know is that that "Line" is above "003.png"